# Missing required packages in Ubuntu 18.04 pcc64el

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, powerpc, singularity-container

starting from [IBM's PowerAI TensorFlow docker container](https://hub.docker.com/r/ibmcom/powerai) I try building a singularity container with additional packages on my Power 9 (ppc64el plattform).
Using apt to install packages I get a lot of missing packages with prevents me from installing my packages.

I already tried using `--fix-missing` option which seems to have no effect.

Is it a problem on ubuntu 18.04 or have I done something wrong.

```
INFO:    Running post scriptlet
+ . /.singularity.d/env/10-docker2singularity.sh
+ export PATH=/usr/local/nvidia/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
+ export PWRAI_USER=pwrai
+ export PWRAI_ID=2051
+ export CONDA_LOCAL=/tmp/conda.sh
+ export CONDA_DIR=anaconda
+ export CONDA_INSTALL_DIR=/opt/anaconda
+ export CONDA_ENV=wmlce
+ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/nvidia/lib:/usr/local/nvidia/lib64
+ export LICENSE_SCRIPT=/var/local/powerai/license_accept.sh
+ export NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=all
+ export NVIDIA_DRIVER_CAPABILITIES=compute,utility
+ export NVIDIA_REQUIRE_CUDA=cuda>=10.1
+ mkdir -p /projects /lustre/ssd /scratch /warm_archive /nvme
+ apt-get update --fix-missing
Hit:1 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic InRelease
Hit:2 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates InRelease
Hit:3 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-backports InRelease
Hit:4 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-security InRelease
Reading package lists...
+ dpkg --configure -a
+ apt-get upgrade -y
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
Calculating upgrade...
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
+ apt-get install -yf apt-utils
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libapt-inst2.0
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  apt-utils libapt-inst2.0
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 276 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1374 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates/main ppc64el libapt-inst2.0 ppc64el 1.6.12 [57.8 kB]
Get:2 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates/main ppc64el apt-utils ppc64el 1.6.12 [218 kB]
debconf: delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed
Fetched 276 kB in 0s (996 kB/s)
Selecting previously unselected package libapt-inst2.0:ppc64el.
(Reading database ... 15839 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libapt-inst2.0_1.6.12_ppc64el.deb ...
Unpacking libapt-inst2.0:ppc64el (1.6.12) ...
Selecting previously unselected package apt-utils.
Preparing to unpack .../apt-utils_1.6.12_ppc64el.deb ...
Unpacking apt-utils (1.6.12) ...
Setting up libapt-inst2.0:ppc64el (1.6.12) ...
Setting up apt-utils (1.6.12) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
+ apt-get install -yf libibverbs-dev ibverbs-utils
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The following additional packages will be installed:
  ibverbs-providers libibverbs1 libnl-3-200 libnl-route-3-200
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  ibverbs-providers ibverbs-utils libibverbs-dev libibverbs1 libnl-3-200
  libnl-route-3-200
0 upgraded, 6 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 530 kB of archives.
After this operation, 3147 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic/main ppc64el libnl-3-200 ppc64el 3.2.29-0ubuntu3 [48.8 kB]
Get:2 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic/main ppc64el libnl-route-3-200 ppc64el 3.2.29-0ubuntu3 [129 kB]
Get:3 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates/main ppc64el libibverbs1 ppc64el 17.1-1ubuntu0.2 [44.2 kB]
Get:4 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates/main ppc64el ibverbs-providers ppc64el 17.1-1ubuntu0.2 [156 kB]
Get:5 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates/universe ppc64el ibverbs-utils ppc64el 17.1-1ubuntu0.2 [49.4 kB]
Get:6 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates/main ppc64el libibverbs-dev ppc64el 17.1-1ubuntu0.2 [103 kB]
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
debconf: (TERM is not set, so the dialog frontend is not usable.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Readline
debconf: (This frontend requires a controlling tty.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Teletype
dpkg-preconfigure: unable to re-open stdin: 
Fetched 530 kB in 0s (2429 kB/s)
Selecting previously unselected package libnl-3-200:ppc64el.
(Reading database ... 15926 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../0-libnl-3-200_3.2.29-0ubuntu3_ppc64el.deb ...
Unpacking libnl-3-200:ppc64el (3.2.29-0ubuntu3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libnl-route-3-200:ppc64el.
Preparing to unpack .../1-libnl-route-3-200_3.2.29-0ubuntu3_ppc64el.deb ...
Unpacking libnl-route-3-200:ppc64el (3.2.29-0ubuntu3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libibverbs1:ppc64el.
Preparing to unpack .../2-libibverbs1_17.1-1ubuntu0.2_ppc64el.deb ...
Unpacking libibverbs1:ppc64el (17.1-1ubuntu0.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package ibverbs-providers:ppc64el.
Preparing to unpack .../3-ibverbs-providers_17.1-1ubuntu0.2_ppc64el.deb ...
Unpacking ibverbs-providers:ppc64el (17.1-1ubuntu0.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package ibverbs-utils.
Preparing to unpack .../4-ibverbs-utils_17.1-1ubuntu0.2_ppc64el.deb ...
Unpacking ibverbs-utils (17.1-1ubuntu0.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libibverbs-dev:ppc64el.
Preparing to unpack .../5-libibverbs-dev_17.1-1ubuntu0.2_ppc64el.deb ...
Unpacking libibverbs-dev:ppc64el (17.1-1ubuntu0.2) ...
Setting up libnl-3-200:ppc64el (3.2.29-0ubuntu3) ...
Setting up libnl-route-3-200:ppc64el (3.2.29-0ubuntu3) ...
Setting up libibverbs1:ppc64el (17.1-1ubuntu0.2) ...
Setting up ibverbs-utils (17.1-1ubuntu0.2) ...
Setting up ibverbs-providers:ppc64el (17.1-1ubuntu0.2) ...
Setting up libibverbs-dev:ppc64el (17.1-1ubuntu0.2) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
+ apt-get install -yf gcc g++ libomp-dev cmake wget git gnupg
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
wget is already the newest version (1.19.4-1ubuntu2.2).
wget set to manually installed.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  binutils binutils-common binutils-powerpc64le-linux-gnu cmake-data cpp cpp-7
  dirmngr g++-7 gcc-7 gcc-7-base git-man gnupg-l10n gnupg-utils gpg gpg-agent
  gpg-wks-client gpg-wks-server gpgconf gpgsm libarchive13 libasan4 libassuan0
  libatomic1 libbinutils libc-dev-bin libc6-dev libcc1-0 libcurl3-gnutls
  liberror-perl libgcc-7-dev libgomp1 libisl19 libitm1 libjsoncpp1 libksba8
  liblsan0 liblzo2-2 libmpc3 libmpfr6 libnpth0 libomp5 librhash0
  libstdc++-7-dev libtsan0 libubsan0 libuv1 linux-libc-dev make manpages
  manpages-dev patch pinentry-curses
Suggested packages:
  binutils-doc cmake-doc ninja-build cpp-doc gcc-7-locales dbus-user-session
  pinentry-gnome3 tor gcc-7-doc libstdc++6-7-dbg gcc-multilib autoconf
  automake libtool flex bison gdb gcc-doc libgcc1-dbg libgomp1-dbg libitm1-dbg
  libatomic1-dbg libasan4-dbg liblsan0-dbg libtsan0-dbg libubsan0-dbg
  libcilkrts5-dbg libmpx2-dbg libquadmath0-dbg gettext-base git-daemon-run
  | git-daemon-sysvinit git-doc git-el git-email git-gui gitk gitweb git-cvs
  git-mediawiki git-svn parcimonie xloadimage scdaemon lrzip glibc-doc
  libomp-doc libstdc++-7-doc make-doc man-browser ed diffutils-doc
  pinentry-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  binutils binutils-common binutils-powerpc64le-linux-gnu cmake cmake-data cpp
  cpp-7 dirmngr g++ g++-7 gcc gcc-7 gcc-7-base git git-man gnupg gnupg-l10n
  gnupg-utils gpg gpg-agent gpg-wks-client gpg-wks-server gpgconf gpgsm
  libarchive13 libasan4 libassuan0 libatomic1 libbinutils libc-dev-bin
  libc6-dev libcc1-0 libcurl3-gnutls liberror-perl libgcc-7-dev libgomp1
  libisl19 libitm1 libjsoncpp1 libksba8 liblsan0 liblzo2-2 libmpc3 libmpfr6
  libnpth0 libomp-dev libomp5 librhash0 libstdc++-7-dev libtsan0 libubsan0
  libuv1 linux-libc-dev make manpages manpages-dev patch pinentry-curses
0 upgraded, 58 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 49.4 MB of archives.
After this operation, 260 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic/main ppc64el liblzo2-2 ppc64el 2.08-1.2 [67.2 kB]
Get:2 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic/main ppc64el manpages all 4.15-1 [1234 kB]
Get:3 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates/main ppc64el binutils-common ppc64el 2.30-21ubuntu1~18.04.2 [193 kB]
Get:4 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates/main ppc64el libbinutils ppc64el 2.30-21ubuntu1~18.04.2 [468 kB]
Get:5 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates/main ppc64el binutils-powerpc64le-linux-gnu ppc64el 2.30-21ubuntu1~18.04.2 [2003 kB]
Get:6 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates/main ppc64el binutils ppc64el 2.30-21ubuntu1~18.04.2 [3392 B]
Get:7 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates/main ppc64el cmake-data all 3.10.2-1ubuntu2.18.04.1 [1332 kB]
Get:8 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates/main ppc64el libarchive13 ppc64el 3.2.2-3.1ubuntu0.5 [352 kB]
Get:9 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic/main ppc64el libjsoncpp1 ppc64el 1.7.4-3 [79.0 kB]
Get:10 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic/main ppc64el librhash0 ppc64el 1.3.6-2 [81.8 kB]
Get:11 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic/main ppc64el libuv1 ppc64el 1.18.0-3 [63.6 kB]
Get:12 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates/main ppc64el cmake ppc64el 3.10.2-1ubuntu2.18.04.1 [3552 kB]
Get:13 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates/main ppc64el gcc-7-base ppc64el 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1 [18.9 kB]
Get:14 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic/main ppc64el libisl19 ppc64el 0.19-1 [588 kB]
Get:15 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic/main ppc64el libmpfr6 ppc64el 4.0.1-1 [230 kB]
Get:16 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic/main ppc64el libmpc3 ppc64el 1.1.0-1 [40.5 kB]
Get:17 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates/main ppc64el cpp-7 ppc64el 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1 [6278 kB]
Get:18 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates/main ppc64el cpp ppc64el 4:7.4.0-1ubuntu2.3 [27.7 kB]
Get:19 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic/main ppc64el libassuan0 ppc64el 2.5.1-2 [33.9 kB]
Get:20 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates/main ppc64el gpgconf ppc64el 2.2.4-1ubuntu1.2 [144 kB]
Get:21 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic/main ppc64el libksba8 ppc64el 1.3.5-2 [90.7 kB]
Get:22 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic/main ppc64el libnpth0 ppc64el 1.5-3 [7780 B]
Get:23 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates/main ppc64el dirmngr ppc64el 2.2.4-1ubuntu1.2 [365 kB]
Get:24 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates/main ppc64el libcc1-0 ppc64el 8.3.0-6ubuntu1~18.04.1 [52.7 kB]
Get:25 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates/main ppc64el libgomp1 ppc64el 8.3.0-6ubuntu1~18.04.1 [80.1 kB]
Get:26 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates/main ppc64el libitm1 ppc64el 8.3.0-6ubuntu1~18.04.1 [29.4 kB]
Get:27 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates/main ppc64el libatomic1 ppc64el 8.3.0-6ubuntu1~18.04.1 [9892 B]
Get:28 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates/main ppc64el libasan4 ppc64el 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1 [366 kB]
Get:29 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates/main ppc64el liblsan0 ppc64el 8.3.0-6ubuntu1~18.04.1 [145 kB]
Get:30 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates/main ppc64el libtsan0 ppc64el 8.3.0-6ubuntu1~18.04.1 [297 kB]
Get:31 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates/main ppc64el libubsan0 ppc64el 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1 [136 kB]
Get:32 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates/main ppc64el libgcc-7-dev ppc64el 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1 [981 kB]
Get:33 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates/main ppc64el gcc-7 ppc64el 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1 [6945 kB]
Get:34 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates/main ppc64el gcc ppc64el 4:7.4.0-1ubuntu2.3 [5204 B]
Get:35 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic/main ppc64el libc-dev-bin ppc64el 2.27-3ubuntu1 [69.7 kB]
Ign:36 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates/main ppc64el linux-libc-dev ppc64el 4.15.0-70.79
Get:37 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic/main ppc64el libc6-dev ppc64el 2.27-3ubuntu1 [2551 kB]
Get:38 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates/main ppc64el libstdc++-7-dev ppc64el 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1 [1535 kB]
Get:39 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates/main ppc64el g++-7 ppc64el 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1 [7127 kB]
Get:40 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates/main ppc64el g++ ppc64el 4:7.4.0-1ubuntu2.3 [1560 B]
Get:41 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates/main ppc64el libcurl3-gnutls ppc64el 7.58.0-2ubuntu3.8 [217 kB]
Get:42 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic/main ppc64el liberror-perl all 0.17025-1 [22.8 kB]
Get:43 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates/main ppc64el git-man all 1:2.17.1-1ubuntu0.4 [803 kB]
Get:44 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates/main ppc64el git ppc64el 1:2.17.1-1ubuntu0.4 [5314 kB]
Get:45 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates/main ppc64el gnupg-l10n all 2.2.4-1ubuntu1.2 [49.6 kB]
Get:46 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates/main ppc64el gnupg-utils ppc64el 2.2.4-1ubuntu1.2 [147 kB]
Get:47 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates/main ppc64el gpg ppc64el 2.2.4-1ubuntu1.2 [526 kB]
Get:48 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic/main ppc64el pinentry-curses ppc64el 1.1.0-1 [38.7 kB]
Get:49 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates/main ppc64el gpg-agent ppc64el 2.2.4-1ubuntu1.2 [260 kB]
Get:50 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates/main ppc64el gpg-wks-client ppc64el 2.2.4-1ubuntu1.2 [112 kB]
Get:51 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates/main ppc64el gpg-wks-server ppc64el 2.2.4-1ubuntu1.2 [104 kB]
Get:52 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates/main ppc64el gpgsm ppc64el 2.2.4-1ubuntu1.2 [247 kB]
Get:53 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates/main ppc64el gnupg ppc64el 2.2.4-1ubuntu1.2 [249 kB]
Get:54 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic/main ppc64el make ppc64el 4.1-9.1ubuntu1 [161 kB]
Get:55 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic/main ppc64el manpages-dev all 4.15-1 [2217 kB]
Get:56 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates/main ppc64el patch ppc64el 2.7.6-2ubuntu1.1 [103 kB]
Get:57 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic/universe ppc64el libomp5 ppc64el 5.0.1-1 [173 kB]
Get:58 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic/universe ppc64el libomp-dev ppc64el 5.0.1-1 [5084 B]
Err:36 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates/main ppc64el linux-libc-dev ppc64el 4.15.0-70.79
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.150 80]
Fetched 48.3 MB in 2s (29.8 MB/s)
E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/l/linux/linux-libc-dev_4.15.0-70.79_ppc64el.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.150 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
FATAL:   post proc: exit status 100
FATAL:   While performing build: while running engine: exit status 255
```

Comment: Did you try to update your local package database via `apt-get update`? There are linux-libc-dev_*_ppc64el.deb packages avialable (e.g. linux-libc-dev_4.15.0-73.82_ppc64el.deb) just not that exact version apt tries to install.

Comment: I ran apt-get update --fix-missing but it didn't change anything. There are serveral other versions of 'problematic' packages available but they seems not to be used by apt.